# Почему в Delphi MinDouble > 0?

Tags: delphi, математика

```
If MinDouble > 0 Then // -> всегда True
If MinDouble < 0 Then // -> всегда False
```

... И как с ним правильно сравнивать?

Попробую подробнее объяснить суть вопроса:
минимальное и максимальное возможное значение для того и нужно, чтобы определять границы диапазона. Для того и заведены эти константы. И то, что минимальное значение больше нуля это странно, т.к. отрицательные значения этому типу никто не запрещал присваивать. На практике получается все отрицательные числа меньше минимального значения, хотя на то оно и минимальное, чтобы меньше его ничего не было.

Comment: Почему бы вам не почитать в документации по Delphi, как определяется MinDouble?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Заблуждение в том, что:

- в отличии от целых чисел, где минимальное - это наиболее отрицательное значение
- минимальное число типа Double (и аналогичных типов с "плавающей" точкой) - это **минимальное отличное от нуля** значение.

Дело в том, что знак числа с точкой кодируется одним битом, и никак не влияет на минимальное / максимальное представляемые этим типом значения.

Таким образом:

- `MinDouble = 5.0e-324;` **Минимальное** представимое число **отличное от нуля**
- `MaxDouble = 1.7e+308;` **Максимальное** представимое число **отличное от нуля**

Положительное или отрицательное число - для этих констант не важно, вы сами добавляете знак как вам нужно. Например, используя 4 числа и знак, получаем вот такие диапазоны:

```
[-MaxDouble .. -MinDouble] 0 [+MinDouble .. +MaxDouble]
```

P.S. И Delphi тут не при чем, в других ЯП всё так же.

Comment: Благодарю за подробное разъяснение!

Comment: _(и аналогичных типов с "плавающей" точкой)_
А как же Comp и Currency? Они тоже относятся к группе этих типов, но минимальные значения соответствуют отрицательным границам.

Comment: @Isaev Currency это тип с фиксированной точкой, а не плавающей. Это не аналогичный тип ;-) (http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Seattle/en/Delphi_Data_Types)

Comment: _можно вас попросить перенести комментарий из под вопроса в сам вопрос?_ Да, конечно, перенёс.

Answer (score 8):

Потому что [*MinDouble*](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/Math_MinDouble.html) определяет минимальное **абсолютное** значение типа double

```
MinDouble = 5.0e-324;
```